# Is there a .contains method in javascript that works similar to Python's implimentation .__contains__()? - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, contains

I'm wondering if there is any implimentation of a `object.contains` method in javascript that works similar to how the Python version `object.__contains__()` works, as in I want to be able to scan the whole object with nested objects to see if there is either a key or a value that does contain what the method is comparing it against. I know there are other ways in Javascript to do this such as using `filter` and `some`, but they don't work for me.

```
person: {
  name: 'Bob',
  age: 40,
  items: {
    cars: 4,
    house: 1,
    computer: 2
  }
}
```

I need something that scans the WHOLE object rather than just the first level of it (which would be `name`, `age`, and `items`, and if you searched for `cars` you wouldn't get any response).

Comment: Not an expert in python, but [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) states "For mapping objects, this should consider the keys of the mapping rather than the values or the key-item pairs." so what you describe is actually not the behavior of contains right?

Comment: not actually sure, I just saw a friend use it in a similar application and assumed the way he did it was the correct way since he's a much more experienced coder than I am..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. A naive take would be

```
JSON.stringify(target).includes( JSON.stringify( search ) )
```

It doesn't work well if `search` is not a string though, as that will also match also inside strings. A non naive approach would be something like this:

```
const contains = (obj, search) => 
 Object.keys(obj).includes(search) ||
 Object.values(obj).includes(search) ||
 Object.values(obj)
   .filter(it => typeof it === "object" && it !== null)
   .some(it => contains(it, search));
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not have a standard function for this i guess but you can for sure write a custom **recursive** function using some `typeof` and `Object.entries()`.

```js
let person =  {
  name: 'Bob',
  age: 40,
  items: {
    cars: 4,
    house: 1,
    computer: 2
  }
};

function searchForTerm(obj,item){
  
  for(let [key,val] of Object.entries(obj)){
    if(key == item){
      return true;
    }
    else if(typeof val === 'object')  
     {
       if(searchForTerm(val,item)){
         return true;
       }
     }
    else if(val == item){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(searchForTerm(person,40));
console.log(searchForTerm(person,43));
console.log(searchForTerm(person,'Bob'));
console.log(searchForTerm(person,'cars'));
console.log(searchForTerm(person,'truck'));
```

I am using `==` in first case, so type checking is not done.

Obviously, this is a starter and you can modify based on your needs. But this should get you going.